# Using OpenXLSX with C++ -> how to set a cell color

Tags: c++, cell, openxlsx

I have OpenXLSX with C++ and I can write data to the cells. Everything works perfectly.
But I can't find a way to set a color for a cell.

When I search for this problem, I find a lot of solutions for R, but not for C++, and I don't find anything in the C++ code.
So I guess it's not possible with C++? Any experience with this?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible with this library.